# Finding trending videos in selected location in youtube api with location

Tags: javascript, react-native, youtube-api

how can I list trending videos in the selected location by sending location data using youtube api?

I will use react native map.

Comment: Is YouTube Data API v3 [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint with [`location`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#location), [`locationRadius`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#locationRadius) and [`order`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#order) what you are looking for?

Comment: i want trend videos

Answer (score 0):

I guess your refer to the following webpage listing *trending videos* for a given country: https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending. You can recover its content by using YouTube Data API v3 [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with parameters [`chart=mostPopular`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#chart) and [`regionCode`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#regionCode).